# How can I change the value of let from a component prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to hide the the card once the time is equal with 0 but the `timeLeft` is never updated. Any idea what am I doing wrong in here?

```
<div style={{ flexDirection: "column", overflowY: "scroll" }}>
  {sorted.map((d, i) => {
    let timeLeft;
      return (
        <div key={i} className="card__container">
          <ProgressBar
            percentage={d.time * 10}
            timing={res => (timeLeft = res)}
          />
        </div>
      );
  })}
</div>
```

My ProgressBar looks like this

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      timeRemainingInSeconds: props.percentage
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.decrementTimeRemaining();
    }, 1000);
  }

  decrementTimeRemaining = () => {
    if (this.state.timeRemainingInSeconds > 0) {
      this.setState({
        timeRemainingInSeconds: this.state.timeRemainingInSeconds - 10
      });
    } else {
      clearInterval(timer);
      this.props.timing(0);
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Progress_wrapper">
        <div
          className="Progress_filler"
          style={{ width: `${this.state.timeRemainingInSeconds / 2}%` }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the variable doesn't get updated, because your map function is kind of a functional component, which therefore is a render function. The variable is basically always reset if you make changes to your parent component.

You could create a real functional component by externalizing it and using a `useState` hook, kind of the following (I really don't know, but this could also work as definition inside your map function):

```
function CardContainer(props) {
    const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(0); // @todo set initial state based on your own definition

      return (
        <div key={i} className="card__container">
          <ProgressBar
            percentage={d.time * 10}
            timing={res => setTimeLeft(res)}
          />
        </div>
      );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**It would be easier if you can reference the library that you are using for `ProgressBar`. If it is not from a library, reference the source code for it.**

I see some issues with the `timing` prop here.

```
<ProgressBar
  percentage={d.time * 10}
  timing={res => (timeLeft = res)}
/>
```

---

My understanding of your props for `ProgressBar`

### Timing

This should be a static value that the component would just display as a visual indicator. We have to take note of the required units for this prop.

### Percentage

This should be a value from `0` to `100` that will decide how the progress bar will visually look like.

### Your question: Hide the component when timing is zero(or perhaps when percentage is at 100?).

For this, we can deploy the strategy to manipulate the style of the div that is wrapping this component.

```
<div style={{ flexDirection: "column", overflowY: "scroll" }}>
  {sorted.map((d, i) => {
    const percentage = d.time * 10; // this is taken from your own computation of percentage. I reckon that you need to divide by 100.
    let customStyle = {};
    if(percentage === 100){
      customStyle = {
        display: "none"
      }
    }

    return (
      <div key={i} className="card__container" style={customStyle}>
        <ProgressBar
          percentage={percentage}
          timing={res => (timeLeft = res)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  })}
</div>
```

Comment: I have updated my question showing the ProgressBar component. So what I am doing I am taking a static value as percentage which can be between 0 to 20 where 20 is 100%. In timing I am returning the value 0 once the decrement is reaching that value. So percentage in the first part is never changed and thats why I want to use let. I would use setState instead but I want to hide only the cards that has reached the 0 value not all of them